# Thread.Sleep() without freezing the UI

Tags: c#, thread-sleep

First off, I am a beginner in `C#` and I would like to make this:

```
class2.method_79(null, RoomItem_0, num, num2, 0, false, true, true);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
class2.method_79(null, RoomItem_0, num, num4, 0, false, true, true);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
class2.method_79(null, RoomItem_0, num, num6, 0, false, true, true);
```

But this solution freezes the UI, how could I make the second event occur 250ms after the first etc without freezing the UI?

Comment: Look up [Multithreading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Do not block the UI thread. Use a worker thread with a sleep. (Note that you can also better use something like a timer). Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11576659/296526 including the link in the answer.

Comment: You could also make the method `async` and use `await Task.Delay(250)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threading in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379240/threading-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Finally I used the async method with await task.delay it works perfectly thanks!!!

Comment: When everyone Not want top make method async it ist possible to use '''Task.Delay(250).Wait()'''

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way to use sleep without freezing the UI thread is to make your method asynchronous. To make your method asynchronous add the **async** modifier.

```
private void someMethod()
```

to

```
private async void someMethod()
```

Now you can use the [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) operator to perform asynchronous tasks, in your case.

```
await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
```

This makes it an [asynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) method and will run asynchronously from your UI thread.

Note that this is only supported in the Microsoft .NET framework 4.5 and higher.

.

Comment: If awaitable type is not needed by` class2.method_79(null, RoomItem_0, num, num4, 0, false, true, true);` and it is not because await void does not returns anything then the timespan between those method will never be as miliseconds given...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Dispatcher Timer](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/) to time your execution of methods..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public static void wait(int milliseconds)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            if (milliseconds == 0 || milliseconds < 0) return;
            timer1.Interval = milliseconds;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Stop();
            };
            while (timer1.Enabled)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the UI thread when you call `.Sleep();`.

That's why it's freezing the UI. If you need to do this without freezing the UI you would need to run the code in separate threads.

Comment: How could I do to apply it in my code ? I am beginner, and never seen how to use multi-threading before...

Comment: @user3640047 You will have to learn. [Here's a good starting point.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Run your time consuming tasks on separate thread. Avoid time consuming tasks and `Thread.Sleep()` on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function in a `Task.Factory.StartNew` and, after that, use `Thread.Sleep()`.

Example:

```
private void btnExample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        MessageBox.Show("First message after one second without freezing");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        MessageBox.Show("Second message after one second without freezing");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        MessageBox.Show("Third message after one second without freezing");
    });
}
```

[image: Testing video]