# Wait a specific time before doing click event

Tags: c#

Hello everyong im working on a project on my C# class. I have a button that generates 3 random pictures after i click this (Slot Machine) and i need to make it generate those pictures after 3 seconds so it seems like its loading.

Comment: What have you looked up and tried to make it wait?

Comment: C# does not have "click events". What context is your code running in?

Comment: At first i checked Thread.Sleep method but many people say it is not good cause it makes the whole programm crash for 3 seconds and you cant do anything else. Then i checked Windows.Forms.Timers but i cant fifure out a way to do the thing i want

Comment: Im talking about this one:private void button1_Click

Comment: I guess this is Winforms.

Comment: Use `await Task.Delay`.

Comment: Thread.Sleep will hang the UI if you are mistakenly doing all your calculations on it..

Answer (score 1):

This won't freeze your UI:

```
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pause your current thread using [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/274eh01d(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
using System.Threading;

TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3); // 3 seconds
Thread.Sleep(interval);
```

Comment: You don't want to do that on a UI thread.

Comment: True, doing that on the UI Thread would cause the UI to freeze for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Thread.Sleep() function. Parameter is given in miliseconds   ´

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //following code
 }
```

If you don't want to freeze the UI. You can use [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136390/thread-sleep-without-freezing-the-ui)

Comment: and hang the UI thread for 5 seconds..